# How to setup a Django CMS 3 menu sitetree?

Tags: django, menu, tree, django-cms

I want to have multiple site trees and, dependent of the role, display the corresponding menu.
For instance; this is my menu:

```
Site      
    Home      
    Products
    Contact

User
    Start      
    Admin
```

Now i can display my menu for a User like this:

```
{% show_menu_below_id "User" 0 1 0 1 %}
```

That will look like this: Start | Admin

The problem is that i want to have it start on "User/Start" and not on "User".

The url: /user/ should actualy by /user/start/

"User" should act like a tree node and i just need it to have an id to display the right tree, but that is about is, i do need it to start at... "Start".

I find it hard to find all ins en outs of Django CMS3 and i am sure/hope this is possible, but can not figure out how? I am not even sure where to look.

Comment: Both "Site" and "User" are "softroots" by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found: add CMS_REDIRECTS = True to the settings.

then you can hardcode a url in the extra fields in the CMS. 
Would be nice if it was not hardcoded, but i can continue now.